# When called by subprocess curl does not understand args

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, subprocess

I am trying to write a python program that needs to download a zip file.

When I call curl with `subprocess.run()` curl no longer understands the provided args.

**Output:**

```
PS F:\z-emwin\emwin-py> python.exe ..\dltest.py
curl: option --url "https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/SL.us008001/CU.EMWIN/DF.xt/DC.gsatR/OPS/txtmin06.zip": is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "..\dltest.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise Exception('CURL ERRORED SEE LOG FILE')
Exception: CURL ERRORED SEE LOG FILE
```

**Code calling curl:**

```
import subprocess as sp

url = 'https://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/SL.us008001/CU.EMWIN/DF.xt/DC.gsatR/OPS/txtmin06.zip'

aaa = (
    'F:/z0bin/curl/bin/curl.exe',
    '--url "{}"'.format(url),
    '--output ftp.zip',
)

p = sp.run(aaa)

if p.returncode > 0:
    raise Exception('CURL ERRORED SEE LOG FILE')
```

## EDIT

Using `[]` gives same result as `()`. Putting url on new line curl says no url given.

Comment: Please try my answer, you have to pass every item as such, not combine them as you have done. e.g. `--url <url>` is wrong, you need to pass `--url,<url>`

Answer (score 1):

To your question: `subprocess.run()` requires the arguements to be passed as a list. Change your `aaa` variable to:

```
aaa = [
    'F:/z0bin/curl/bin/curl.exe',
    '--url',
      "{}".format(url),
    '--output',
     'ftp.zip',
]
```

but if you want to have less hassle in future, you can just use pythons own `requests` library to download from web.